# Route not found while using devise_scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am trying to use devise_scope to redirect my /login to devise controller and views. But at the same time I want to use /users/sign_in default devise path also, that's why I didn't include skip [:sessions] in devise for. But I am getting error

```
undefined method `user_session_path' for #<Module:0x00564e34f44268
```

routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, :class_name => '::User', :controllers => {
      :registrations => "users/registrations",
      :invitations => 'users/invitations',
      :confirmations => 'users/confirmations',
      :passwords => 'users/passwords'        
    }
devise_scope :user do        
   get 'login', :action => :new, :controller => 'devise/sessions'      
end
```

devise/sessions/new.html.erb

```
<div class="app-section-body">
      <%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name), :html => { :class => 'form-vertical', :spellcheck => 'false' }) do |f| %>
```

This works with /users/sign_in but throws error in /login

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `/` in `get '/login'`

You can simplify it a bit with this

```
devise_scope :user do        
   get '/login', to: 'devise/sessions#new'    
end
```

Comment: The problem is not redirection, that works perfectly but after redirection it throws error in the post url line.

Comment: My bad, you're right and the `/` actually doesn't matter. I have a dummy devise app I use to test stuff out, and I can't reproduce your error given the code you've posted. I copied your routes exactly and the top line of the `simple_form_for` is the same, using the `simple_form` gem

Comment: @ShilpiKayal you should post your `rake routes`, the full sign_in form, and the `SessionsController` if you have modified it. Also, what version of `Devise` are you using?

Comment: @m.simonborg: since the `/` doesn't matter, please delete that part from this answer